# Select statement blocks the read/write operation on the InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a Select query which executes on a transactional table having more than 4 million records. Whenever I execute this query , I observe that all write and update operations on that particular transactional table become suspended and we start getting exceptions from java side that lock wait timeout exceeds , try restarting transaction. Currently lock wait timeout is set to 200 seconds. I am unable to understand that why a select statement can create such locks on the table and block all insert/update statements. The table storage engine is InnoDb and primary key is auto-increment key. The MySQL Version is 5.1.40. 
Also I m not starting any transaction before executing select statement.

Any Idea?

Comment: Have you tried an EXPLAIN on the query? What did it say?

Comment: yes I have tried Explain. It shows that all indexes are hitting.

Answer (score 0):

So, yes, your SELECT in one transaction read-locks the records of that table and write operations which touch the same records will have to wait until read transaction completes (if it follows two phase locking).

[This document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-lock-modes.html) may help understanding innodb locks model