# Can a simple SELECT statement block processes when there is no open transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I encountered a weird scenario a couple of days ago, when a simple SELECT statement that returned 4 rows of data was causing a blocking chain in SQL server. There was no open transactions. Any inkling why this might occur?

Comment: Was it deadlocked?  Reads need to lock because the data may change during the read.  Reading without locks is possible and is known as a dirty read because it may contain partially committed data

Comment: If that is of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738647/select-statement-blocks-the-read-write-operation-on-the-innodb-table? MySQL and InnoDB  though.

Comment: There are different lock types though and it may be worth reading up on lock types,  compatibility and lock escalation. Two shared locks held by two select statements will not block each other because neither one is altering data,  however an update places a more strict lock on tables, rows or ranges of rows in order to prevent dirty data being read

Comment: @Charleh well it was causing a deadlock on other processes...I run select statements all the time..and it's the first time something like that happened where it's causing a block on other processes.

Comment: @dollarvar It does shed some light but I am only returning 4 rows of data...could there be another explanation?

Comment: Yeah likely another process had taken out a more strict lock and was waiting on the select, but the select was waiting on something else and so on until a loop was formed,  hence a deadlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes a simple SELECT statement can endup in deadlock , Imagine a
>   scenario where  User1 is only reading data and User2 trys to Update
>   some data and there a non-clustered index on that table, it is
>   possible.
>
> 1) User1 is reading Some Data and obtains a shared lock on the
>   non-clustered index in order to perform a lookup, and then tries to
>   obtain a shared lock on the page contianing the data in order to
>   return the data itself.
>
> 2) User2 who is writing/Updating first obtains an exlusive lock on the
>   database page containing the data, and then attempts to obtain an
>   exclusive lock on the index in order to update the index.

<kbd>[Read here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)</kbd> to learn more about locking in sql-server.

Comment: Sir, Could you link to some documents for: `shared lock` and `exclusive lock`? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if there was no Update, but let's say users are trying to hit a page on a site whereby a procedure in the backend is getting called. Would the SELECT statement have caused a deadlock as well?

Comment: @ShaunK Yes it is still possible if one select statement has a more strict transaction isolation level which obtains exclusive locks on the data pages, you can end up having a dead lock in that situation as well.